# How to echo SESSION variable in <ul>

Tags: php, html, session, html-lists

I have PHP SESSION variables that I know work. However, when I try to echo them in a  they don't work.

I can print the SESSION variables in regular code just fine. However, they don't show up in the following code:

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown-hover">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle pr-0" data-toggle="dropdown" 
href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i data-feather="user"></i> Hi, <?php echo $first_name; ?>  
<i data-feather="chevron-down"></i>
          </a>
```

I assure you the rest of the code works. I just don't know how to echo $first_name in the above location.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: hum, $_SESION['first_name']?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown-hover">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle pr-0" data-toggle="dropdown" 
href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i data-feather="user"></i> Hi, <?php echo $_SESSION['first_name']; ?>  
   <i data-feather="chevron-down"></i>
      </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Creating Session

```
<?php
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  global variable*/
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
?>
```

## Getting Session

```
<?php
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  global variable*/
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
/*session created*/
echo $_SESSION["newsession"];
/*session was getting*/
?>
```

## Updating Session

```
<?php
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  global variable*/
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
/*it is my new session*/
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$updatedvalue;
/*session updated*/
?>
```

## Deleting Session

```
<?php
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  global variable*/
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
unset($_SESSION["newsession"]);
/*session deleted. if you try using this you've got an error*/
?>
```

Comment: How does this help OP?

Answer (score 0):

also please check your session is start

You should use $_SESSION['var_name'];
like $_SESSION['first_name'];

or use extract function to get first_name as a variable.